# pandas compare multiple column values from different frames of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame with GPS coordinates and I'm trying to make an offline reverse geocode city lookup service. I'm essentially trying to resolve the city name from a pair of GPS coordinates. I cannot use 3rd party services.

My data frame looks like this:

```
data = [
    ["LATITUDE","LONGITUDE"],
    [41.9021454,-87.624176],
    [38.8898163,-76.9598312],
    [39.304615,-76.6136703],
    [38.9550285,-76.7441483],
    [41.8815498,-87.6620789],
    [33.9141922,-84.3123169]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0])

LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
41.9021454  -87.624176
38.8898163  -76.9598312
39.304615   -76.6136703
38.9550285  -76.7441483
41.8815498  -87.6620789
33.9141922  -84.3123169
```

I made a city lookup data frame

```
city_data = [
    ['CITY',"LAT","LON"],
    ['PHOENIX',33.0,-112.0],
    ['ATLANTA',33.0,-84.0],
    ['MIAMI',25.0,-80.0],
    ['WASHINGTON_DC',39.0,-77.0],
    ['CHICAGO',41.0,-87.0],
]
df_geo = pd.DataFrame(city_data[1:],columns=city_data[0])

            CITY   LAT    LON
0        PHOENIX  33.0 -112.0
1        ATLANTA  33.0  -84.0
2          MIAMI  25.0  -80.0
3  WASHINGTON_DC  39.0  -77.0
4        CHICAGO  41.0  -87.0
```

I want to compare the lat and lon of both data frames to see if the values are ~roughly +/- 1 within each other and if so make a new column with the city name like this:

```
LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   CITY
41.9021454  -87.624176  CHICAGO
38.8898163  -76.9598312 WASHINGTON_DC
39.304615   -76.6136703 WASHINGTON_DC
38.9550285  -76.7441483 WASHINGTON_DC
41.8815498  -87.6620789 CHICAGO
33.9141922  -84.3123169 ATLANTA
```

The data frames are of different lengths. The city lookup might be 10 rows but the data might be thousands. I'm pretty sure the comparison can be done in one line with np.where or df.isin but I don't know how to say it. I have this but I'm stuck

```
df['city'] = np.where(abs(df['LATITUDE'] - df_geo.loc[df["LAT"]]) <= 1  and
                      abs(df['LONGITUDE'] - df_geo.loc[df["LON"]]) <= 1, df_geo['CITY'], 'TBD')


df['city'] = np.where(df['LATITUDE'].round(0) in df_geo['LAT'] and
                      df['LONGITUDE'] in df_geo['LON'] , df_geo['CITY'], 'TBD')
```

Comment: `~roughly +/- 1` ... +/- 1 of what?

Comment: +/- 1 of each other. So a coordinate like 87.429323 would be valid for == to 86, 87, 88 or 89 in the city lookup. It's just approximate.

Comment: Okay, the first example was PHOENIX initially, which confused me.

Comment: In your example, `df_geo` has all positive longitudes. That can't be right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some cool stuff with numpy. Here's one solution using broadcasted comparison.

```
i = df.values[:, None]
j = df_geo.values[None, :, 1:].astype(float)    

df['CITY'] = df_geo.CITY.iloc[
                   (np.abs(j - i) <= 1).all(2).argmax(1)
             ].values

df

    LATITUDE  LONGITUDE           CITY
0  41.902145 -87.624176        CHICAGO
1  38.889816 -76.959831  WASHINGTON_DC
2  39.304615 -76.613670  WASHINGTON_DC
3  38.955028 -76.744148  WASHINGTON_DC
4  41.881550 -87.662079        CHICAGO
5  33.914192 -84.312317        ATLANTA
```

This is *fast*. But watch out, this eats memory, especially with larger datasets.

Comment: Smart. One issue: if no City found, this defaults to 0 index [i.e. Phoenix].

Comment: @jp_data_analysis ...yeah :( Thanks for pointing that out. Not sure I can help that though, your solution would be ++ in that sense so +1  :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I don't know how else to repay you :)

Comment: @Calculus Send 100 dollars to my PayPal... heheh just kidding, you're welcome.

Comment: I can set the 0 index to mean "TBD" Thanks for pointing that out. You guys are great.

Comment: @Calculus smart move. You can vote on/accept your favourite answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a crude solution in terms of performance, but it should provide a framework:

```
df_geo['GPS'] = list(zip(df_geo.LAT, df_geo.LON))
geo_map = df_geo.set_index('CITY')['GPS'].to_dict()

# {'ATLANTA': (33.0, -84.0),
#  'CHICAGO': (41.0, -87.0),
#  'MIAMI': (25.0, -80.0),
#  'PHOENIX': (33.0, 112.0),
#  'WASHINGTON_DC': (39.0, -77.0)}

def calculator(row, mapper, error):
    for k, v in mapper.items():
        if abs(row['LATITUDE'] - v[0]) <= error and \
           abs(row['LONGITUDE'] - v[1]) <= error:
            return k
    else:
        return None

df['CITY'] = df.apply(calculator, mapper=geo_map, error=1, axis=1)

#     LATITUDE  LONGITUDE           CITY
# 0  41.902145 -87.624176        CHICAGO
# 1  38.889816 -76.959831  WASHINGTON_DC
# 2  39.304615 -76.613670  WASHINGTON_DC
# 3  38.955028 -76.744148  WASHINGTON_DC
# 4  41.881550 -87.662079        CHICAGO
# 5  33.914192 -84.312317        ATLANTA
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works too. I will have the chance to run this against a data set of a billion rows in the next couple of months. I'll report back on the performance of both approaches.

Comment: @Calculus, sure. coldspeed's approach is undoubtedly faster, but will give errors if there are no matches (while mine gives None).